# ¿Como filtrar dos o mas palabras en una cadena de texto en js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objeto, filtro, frontend

Tengo un objeto que contiene una cadena de strings:
 `{descripcion: "Auricular Logitech G430"}`
Si en el input escribo por ej. "auricular logitech", el `.includes()` me trae el el objeto perfectamente.
Pero si escribo por ej. "auricular g430", el `.includes()` no me devuelve nada. ¿Hay algun metodo para que al filtrar "auricular g430" me traiga el objeto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lamentablemente includes() devuelve true o false dependiendo si la cadena exacta está contenida en otra (y por cierto, también es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas).

### Método tradicional sin expresiones regulares

Como complemento a la respuesta de [@Killbunny](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/525068/274002), la cual aconsejo directamente. Por el rendimiento no te preocupes, porque ambas formas son extremadamente pesadas, las expresiones regulares dinámicas son lentas tanto en construcción como en ejecución, y partir con splits y buscar por palabras es también horrible.

Las ventajas de usar métodos residen únicamente en si quieres añadir búsquedas avanzadas, si quieres tener mejor control de los filtros. Si sólo buscas lo que propones, insisto, la respuesta de @Killbunny es suficiente.

```js
function incluyeAlguna(original, buscadas) {
    return buscadas.split(' ')
                   .some(p => original.includes(p))
}

function incluyeTodas(original, buscadas) {
    return buscadas.split(' ')
                   .every(p => original.includes(p))
}
```

#### Snippet con casos de prueba

```js
function incluyeAlguna(original, buscadas) {
    return buscadas.split(' ')
                   .some(p => original.includes(p))
}

function incluyeTodas(original, buscadas) {
    return buscadas.split(' ')
                   .every(p => original.includes(p))
}

const desc = "Logitech Auricular G430"

input = "G430 Auricular"
console.log( incluyeTodas(desc, input) );
// true porque descripción contiene todas

input = "G430 Auricular Especial"
console.log( incluyeTodas(desc, input) );
// false porque no contiene especial

input = "g430 auRiCular"
console.log(
  incluyeTodas(
      desc.toLowerCase(), 
      input.toLowerCase()
  )
);
// true porque contiene todas, usando toLowerCase 
// para comparar solo con minúsculas

input = "G430 no importa el resto"
console.log( incluyeAlguna(desc, input) );
// true porque contiene alguna (G430)
```

### Explicación de las funciones

El método `split()` parte una string en un array de palabras, separando por un separador (en este caso un espacio). En este caso está supersimplificado porque no sé que tipo de tratamiento del input haces, pero es aconsejable primero usar trim() (`buscadas.trim().split(...)`) para eliminar espacios por delante y por detrás del input. Y dentro del split, no usar meramente un carácter espacio como separador, sino una expresión regular que admita más separadores y longitud de los mismos, aunque ya para eso puedes usar una solución con expresiones regulares.

Llamamos al método `.some()` del array devuelto, es una especie de forEach que recibe un predicado y devuelve true si encuentra algún elemento que lo cumpla. En el caso de incluyeAlguna, nuestro predicado es `Alguna palabra p que esté contenida en original`. Si encuentra alguna, devuelve true, que es lo que finalmente devolvemos.

<del>En el caso del incluyeTodas, nuestro predicado es `Alguna palabra que NO esté incluida en original`. Si encuentra alguna (true) debemos devolver false, por ello negamos el resultado final en el return.</del>

### Actualización 6/11/2022

Además de `some` existe el método funcional `every`, que devuelve true si todos los elementos cumplen el predicado. Con `every` usado en incluyeTodas el predicado vendría a ser `Si todas las palabras p están contenidas en original`.

Comment: Perfecto! Me sirvió el metodo incluyeTodas. Muchas gracias Alexander

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separar tus filtros de búsqueda y luego usar usar RegExp para hacer test sobre ellos y encontrar los matches totales o parciales

```js
var articulo = "Auricular Logitech G430";
var filtrobusqueda = "auricular g430" //true
//var filtrobusqueda = "auri logi g430" //true
//var filtrobusqueda = "aurocular g430" //true
//var filtrobusqueda = "aurocular g431" //false
articulo = articulo.toUpperCase();
filtrobusqueda= filtrobusqueda.toUpperCase();
//var filtros = filtrobusqueda.split(" ");
//var contieneParcial = new RegExp(filtros.join('|')).test(articulo);
var filtros = filtrobusqueda.replace(' ','|');
var contieneParcial = new RegExp(filtros).test(articulo);
console.log('Contiene total o parcial:'+contieneParcial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola y si el includes lo cambias por una funcion propia:

```
function ContienePalabra(descripcion, buscar){ 
    
    let splitBuscar = buscar.split(" ");
    for(let i = 0; i < splitBuscar.length; i++){

        if(descripcion.toLowerCase().includes(splitBuscar[i].toLowerCase())) {
           return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

ContienePalabra('Auricular Logitech G430', 'auricular logitech') //true

ContienePalabra('Auricular Logitech G430', 'G431') //False

ContienePalabra('Auricular Logitech G430', 'auricular logitech') //True

Comment: 1. No funciona, este método sólo analiza la primera palabra (si se incluye devuelve true, y si no, devuelve false, dado que tienes el return false dentro del for)

2. Estás realizando un toLowerCase() a descripción continuamente en cada iteración, lo suyo sería realizarlo una sola vez ya que es un dato que no cambia.